# How can i turn these two functions into a turn by turn for Naughts and crosses

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, variables

I have two functions (one that runs)
I'm wanting to use these and create two player turn variables to switch between each other marking an X or an O when it's each players turn. I'm wanting to keep it as simple as possible but cannot even fathom where to go. I know it's not great but if I can I would like to keep these functions or something close to it.

```
   <section class="allBoxes">
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box2"></div>
        <div class="box3"></div>
        <div class="box4"></div>
        <div class="box5"></div>
        <div class="box6"></div>
        <div class="box7"></div>
        <div class="box8"></div>
        <div class="box9"></div>
        <script src="tictac.js"></script>
      </section>

function clickBoxPlayerOne(event) {
  var boxClicked = event.target;
  if ((boxClicked.textContent = " ")) boxClicked.textContent = "X";
}
var allBoxes = document.querySelector(".allBoxes");
allBoxes.addEventListener("click", clickBoxPlayerOne);

function clickBoxPlayerTwo(event) {
  var boxClicked = event.target;
  if (boxClicked.textContent != "X") boxClicked.textContent = "O";
}
var allBoxes = document.querySelector(".allBoxes");
allBoxes.addEventListener("click", clickBoxPlayerTwo);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a global variable to keep the current player state and update it whenever the user clicks on any box. Like in the Tic-tac-toe :)

Adding a sample working code for reference to see how the usage is.

```js
const player1 = "X", player2 = "O";
let currentPlayer = player1;

const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tile");
// Click handler
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', playMe, false);
}

function playMe(event) {
  if(event.target.innerText == "") {
    event.target.innerText = currentPlayer;
    currentPlayer = currentPlayer == player1 ? player2 : player1;
  }
}
```

```css
.tile {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.row {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row"><span class="tile"></span><span class="tile"></span><span class="tile"></span></div>
  <div class="row"><span class="tile"></span><span class="tile"></span><span class="tile"></span></div>
  <div class="row"><span class="tile"></span><span class="tile"></span><span class="tile"></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the need for global variables I would use the function that's called from `addEventListener` to set up those variables, and return a new function (closure) that is the function that's returned to the listener. The closure maintains the variables in its local lexical environment so it can update them.

I would also use CSS Grid to handle the display.

```js
const allBoxes = document.querySelector('.allboxes');

allBoxes.addEventListener('click', handleClick(), false);

function handleClick() {
  
  // Initialise the player variable
  let player = 1;

  // Return the function that will be used
  // when the listener is called
  return function (e) {

    // Get the text content of the clicked element
    const { textContent } = e.target;

    if (!textContent) {

      // Update the content of the square, and
      // then swap the player
      const content = player === 1 ? 'X' : 'O';
      e.target.textContent = content;
      player = player === 1 ? 2 : 1;
    }

  }

}
```

```css
.allboxes { width: 50%; display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); gap: 0.5em; }
.allboxes div { display: flex; border: 1px solid black; height: 2em; width: 2em; align-items: center; justify-content: center;}
```

```html
<div class="allboxes">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```